# FInding error developing API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I juts start with the developing of an API using RAILS. Im doing a simple example of my own but I have an error when I want to see the result in my API.

Controller:

```
class EnergyCalcController < ApplicationController
  def index
    file_path = Rails.root.join('db','test_file.js')  
     file_gen = File.read(file_path) 
     @data_hash_gen = JSON.parse(file_gen)  


  end
end
```

In controllers/api/energy_calc_controller.rb

```
class Api::EnergyCalcController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render json: @data_hash_gen 
    end

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :energy_calc
  end
  get 'energy_calc/index'
```

Views/energy_calc/index.html.erb

```
<h1>EnergyCalc#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/energy_calc/index.html.erb</p>
<%= @data_hash_gen %>
```

In the view is printing me the data normally. But when I tried to access: http://localhost:3000/api/energy_calc.json I got `null`

Any idea?

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/api/energy_calc.json`

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly my address

Comment: Have you assigned value for @data_hash_gen in index of Api::EnergyCalcController? Because I see, the instance variable is set only on index of EnergyCalcController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `EnergyCalcController` index methods code in to `Api::EnergyCalcController's` index method. Like this,

```
class Api::EnergyCalcController < ApplicationController
  def index
    file_path = Rails.root.join('db','test_file.js')  
    file_gen = File.read(file_path) 
    @data_hash_gen = JSON.parse(file_gen)  
    render json: @data_hash_gen 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two different controllers for rendering different formats.It is redundant.You could render HTML and JSON both in a single action.

```
class EnergyCalcController < ApplicationController

    def index
      file_path = Rails.root.join('db','test_file.js')  
      file_gen = File.read(file_path) 
      @data_hash_gen = JSON.parse(file_gen)  
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
          render :json => @data_hash_gen
        }
        format.html {
          #Objects exclusively needed to render html
        }
      end
    end

end
```